# C++ not implicitly casting in friend function operator?

Tags: c++, casting, operators

How does C++ go about implicitly casting when it comes to friend function?

This is my friend function implementation :

```
bool operator==(Point& x, Point& y) {
    return x.x == y.x;
}
```

In my class I have a simple converstion constructor :

```
Point(int x=5) : x(x){}
```

Why does the following code not implicitly convert int into my class Point ?

```
cout << (p == 5) << endl;
cout << (5 == p) << endl;
```

Comment: You need to have `const Point&`  as arguments for the `operator==`

Comment: Or just `Point`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with friend functions or operator overloads by the way. You would have seen the same behavior with any function and trying to do any kind of conversion to a parameter of non-`const` (lvalue) reference type.